# Statistical significance of Moran I

Tags: raster, r, autocorrelation, moran-index

I would like to estimate the Moran's I coefficient for raster data together with the statistical significance of the spatial autocorrelation obtained.

I found that the raster package function `Moran()` although calculates the spatial autocorrelation index it apparently does not give directly the statistical significance of the results obtained: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/raster/html/autocor.html

Could it be possible to obtain the statistical significance of the results with either a raster package or similar one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a monte-carlo test of `I>0`:

First lets create a very correlated raster:

```
> r = raster(matrix(1:(50*50),50,50))
> Moran(r)
[1] 0.9694908
```

And now do 99 Moran's I of rasters that are random samplings of those values:

```
> M99 = sapply(1:99, function(i){v = r; v[]=sample(r[]);Moran(v)})
```

And let's see the distribution:

```
> hist(M99)
> range(M99)
[1] -0.02713834  0.02061854
```

And its clear that the `Moran(r)` is way outside the range of the simulations, so we can reject the null that the data are uncorrelated with respect to random sampling/rearrangement of the data.

To get the approximate pseudo p-value, see where the Moran stat for the data ranks amongst the simulations. Suppose the Moran stat for the data was 0.018 (using the 0.969 example from my code is a bit extreme), then compute the rank:

```
> rank(c(0.018, M99))[1]
[1] 98
```

Which shoes that 0.018 ranks 98 out of the 100 values (99 sims + itself). Hence reject H0 (no spatial autocorrelation under random arrangement hypothesis) with approximate p = 0.98.

If you do more simulations, then the general case is:

```
> R/(length(M99)+1)
[1] 0.98
```

for any number of simulations in M99.

This is what `moran.mc` from the `spdep` package does with data for polygons or other general neighbourhood structures.

Alternatively convert your raster to a grid of polygons and use the `spdep` functions with either 4-way or 8-way neighbours (or beyond...)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer is indeed very helpful ! Just a question the value of 99 is valid for any raster layer size or should be related to the size of the raster layer?

Comment: That's the number of monte-carlo simulations to do. The more you do, the more precise is your estimate of the (pseudo) p-value. 99 simulations plus your observational data mean your p-value is the rank of the observation out of 100 - in this case 100/100, and I can say p > 0.99. If I did 999 sims and it was still largest, that would be p > 0.999. If I did 999 sims and it was 994th, then p>0.994. See ?moran.mc in spdep and general MC test theory

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation.

Comment: is there any chance to get for the same example code  another line for obtaining the correspondent p-value to that example?

Comment: Just a question to clarify myself with regards to pseudo p-value estimation: in my case Moran(r) = 0.6461546, so the pseudo p-value would be 1, right? since rank(c(0.6461546, M99))[1] is 100, so pseudo would p-value = 1 then, H0 is rejected, right ?

Comment: Yes, you can also look at `hist(M99)` and see where your 0.646 is - I suspect its off the scale. That sort of correlation should be visibly non-random - the Moran stat just confirms it!

Comment: This looks like a new question - pad it out with an example and post it up.

Comment: ok I will open a new question thanks.

Comment: Yes the 0.646 is out scale as you mention. Thanks !